# Unable to execute datediff command on centos as root user?

Tags: bash, centos, datediff

I am unable to run the datediff command as root user on centos. But as the other user, I can run the command. Could you guys, please help me to fix the issue?

FYI, I'm using this version centos-release-7-0.1406.el7.centos.2.5.x86_64

Comment: Check your `$PATH` variable, the command's directory is probably not in there for your root user.

Comment: @Nic3500 thanks dude. this is really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `$PATH` variable, the command's directory is probably not in there for your root user.

```
echo $PATH
```

Will show the current value, the directory of the `datediff` command must appear in there.  To modify, do:

```
export PATH=$PATH:<THE DIRECTORY>
```

To find where `datediff` resides on your system, while you are connected with another user than root, do:

```
which datediff
```